# How to fix this unexpected token '!=' error

Tags: r, unexpected-token

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I couldn't find an answer on the internet before. Maybe anyone of you could help me to fix the error.

It says unexpected token '!='. The following is the code:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE) 
if((!= is.null(args[1])) && (!=is.na(args[1]))) filename = args[1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Please provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `if((!is.null(args[1])) && (!is.na(args[1]))) filename = args[1]`

`!=` operator (not equal to) is used with tested object on the left and the expected value on the right `if((is.null(args[1]) != TRUE)`